# Merkle Tree Data Synchronization False Positives

Tags: algorithm, cassandra, probability, amazon-dynamodb, hashtree

Merkle trees (aka hash trees) are used for data synchronization in both "Cassandra" & "Dynamo".

As with any hash function, there is a probability that different data can have the same hash value:

There exists an x and y where [y!=x] but [hash(x) = hash(y)]

As the "big data" in NOSQL grows, the probability of encountering such data becomes higher.

This means that as data sets get bigger, it is almost certain that different nodes in the Merkle tree will yield the same parent hash.

On such an occasion, when two different machines in the cluster traverse their merkle trees, they will get a false positive that their data is consistent. If no more data is written to that branch of the tree, the machines will remain unsynchronized forever.

How is this handled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most systems don't handle this. Why? Because the probability of having two different inputs that have the same hash value is very, very low. With a good hash function (which I think you are using), this should approach 1/2^{hash-bits}. And since most hashes for these purposes are at least 128 bits long, you get a probability of 1/2^128 of such a collision. Which is about 2.9387359e-39 (0.{38 zeroes}29387359).

Using a hash of 160 bits (which most of these systems use, SHA-1 hashes), is good enough that when you have as much objects in your database as there are grains of sand in the world. That you still have less than a probability of 1/2 that there will be such a collision. Thus, I wouldn't worry about the case where there is a collision. The probability of that happening, is really way too low.

Comment: Is there another sync mechanism which would eventually kick in here? Or do these databases simply rely on the hash-functions being uniformly distributed? I remind you that in the case of Cassandra most users go with a default hash function, which probably does not have optimal distribution.

Comment: No, most systems rely on hash-functions being uniformly distributed (they rely on [SUHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SUHA_(computer_science)). And I highly doubt that the default hash function of Cassandra does not use SUHA.

Comment: How could cassandra assume equal distribution over data which is not theirs? The user can always write data which does not play well with the hash function.

Comment: In theory, yes, the user could do that. However, that involves specificially finding a collision in a hash function. And that is something that requires a LOT of computing power. Also, since a system like Cassandra doesn't just hash over the data, but also over the metadata, you would also have to make sure that the metadata is exactly how you want it. Which makes the problem a lot harder.